# I'm trying to get a list of items with enumerate and Vdots

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to format the textBf phrase as headings:

like:

**Category 1:** Incident tickets that can be closed with a less number of updating histories

**Category 2:** Incident ticket that can be closed with a average number of updating histories

`\vdots`

**Category N:** Incident ticket that can be closed with a very high number of updatinghistories

So far I have got this. How to get the next line to begin in parallel to the sentence but not the heading

```
\begin{enumerate}[]

\item\textbf{Category 1:} Incident tickets that can be closed with a less number of updating histories
\item\textbf{Category 2:} Incident ticket that can be closed with a average number of updating histories
\item[]{$\vdots$} 
\item\textbf{Category \textit{N}:} Incident ticket that can be closed with a very high number of updating histories
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following (it uses `enumitem` to simplify the first few items' input):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Category \arabic*:}]
  \item Incident tickets that can be closed with a less number of updating
    histories
  \item Incident ticket that can be closed with a average number of updating
    histories
  \item[{$\vdots$}] 
  \item[\textbf{Category $\bm{N}$:}] Incident ticket that can be closed with a very
    high number of updating histories
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this variant layout, obtained with `enumitem` and `makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makebox}
\newlength{\mymargin}
\settowidth{\mymargin}{\textbf{Category \emph{N}:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Category \arabic*:, font=\bfseries, wide=0pt, labelwidth=\mymargin, leftmargin =!, labelsep=0.4em]% 
\item Incident tickets that can be closed with a less number of updating histories.

\item Incident ticket that can be closed with an average number of updating historie. \vspace{-1ex}

\item[\makebox*{\textbf{Category }}{$\vdots$}]\vspace*{-1ex}

\item[Category \emph{N}:]Incident ticket that can be closed with a very high number of updating histories. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]